# Проблема с обучением сети в Keras: нет обобщающей способности сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Пытаюсь решить свою задачу путем использования Keras (новичок в нем и в языке python). Задача заключается в том, чтобы входным векторам присваивать значения на выходе в виде определенного числа. Вектор входной состоит из нулей и единиц (длина 3002), и появление единиц в векторе, а также места их расположения логически обоснованы. Выходные значения находятся в промежутке от 30 до 100. 
То есть правильно обученная сеть, по идее, должна находить эту закономерность.
Пробовал различные конфигурации собирать (менять число слоёв, нейронов, эпох обучения, оптимизаторы разные, включать dropout и regularizers), но результат на тестовой выборке выходит неудовлетворительным.

Верхнюю часть кода с обработкой данных не вставлял, там нет ничего интересного.

Прилагаю конфигурацию сети:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
Adelta = optimizers.Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
model.compile( optimizer=Adelta, loss="mse", metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, 
verbose=2,validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Результат обучения

```
Epoch 100/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.1438 - mean_absolute_error: 0.3181 - val_loss: 404.9491 - 
val_mean_absolute_error: 17.4352
```

Количество векторов - 71. Тренировочная выборка состоит из 36 векторов и в соответствие им ставятся четные выходные значения (30, 32 и т.п. до 100).
Если проверить на тренировочной выборке, то сеть выдает правильные ответы (в пределах погрешности), однако на тестовой все ответы не верны. 
Пример работы на тренировочной выборке (первые четыре ответа):

```
predictions=model.predict(x_train)
print(predictions)
[[ 30.192966]
[ 32.436104]
[ 33.91804 ]
[ 36.463882]
```

Пример на тестовой:

```
predictions=model.predict(x_test)
print(predictions)
# правильные ответы: 31, 33, 35, 37
[[64.25001 ]
[61.841393]
[63.196877]
[66.39989 ]
```

Надеюсь описание проблемы мною дано адекватное. Нормализацию данных не делал, так как вектор и так, по сути, нормализован и данные находятся в интервале [0,1]. 
Что, по-вашему мнению, нужно изменить в модели, чтобы приблизиться к правильному обучению сети?

UPD

```
#загружаем файл с образами
TRAIN_FILE="traindata30_100km.csv"
TEST_FILE="testdata30_100km.csv"

# размер вектора
img_rows, img_cols = 1, 3002

# Загружаем данные для обучения
train_dataset = np.loadtxt(TRAIN_FILE, skiprows=0, dtype='int', 
delimiter=",")
test_dataset = np.loadtxt(TEST_FILE, skiprows=0, dtype='int', delimiter=",")

# Выделяем данные для обучения
x_train = train_dataset[:, 1:]
x_test = test_dataset[:, 1:]
# Выделяем правильные ответы
y_train = train_dataset[:,0]
y_test = test_dataset[:,0]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80855/discussion-on-question-by-aleksandr------keras--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из серии вопросов-ответов в комментариях можно сделать следующие выводы:

1. Оригинальные входные данные (матрица с 3002 столбцами) были преобразованы к бинарному виду - нули и единицы. Этим вы лишили НС львиной доли входной информации. Из 159.106 входных значений только `0.1%` - ненулевые:

   ```
   In [80]: x_train.sum()
   Out[80]: 115

   In [81]: x_train.size
   Out[81]: 108072

   In [82]: x_train.sum() / x_train.size
   Out[82]: 0.0010641054112073432
   ```
2. набор данных для обучения слишком маленький
3. если работать с оригинальными (не "бинаризированными") данными, то можно попробовать построить более интересную / глубокую НС.

Comment: К сожалению, задача такова, что получить огромную выборку будет мягко говоря сложно. 
Неужели нельзя найти решение при такой постановке? Или в погоне за упрощением входного вектора я потерял возможные неявные признаки, которые для НС были бы полезны?
В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: @Aleksandr, можно попробовать и с маленьким обучающим набором, но вы "упростили" ваши данные на `99.9%` - ожидать какой-либо приемлимой точности предсказаний, в этом случае, я бы не стал...

Comment: Упростил так упростил. Найду свои оригинальные данные и попробую повторить обучение ИНС, и нормализую данные, как вы посоветовали.