# Какие могут быть пути улучшения обобщающей способности ИНС на базе Keras?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Несколько дней назад я создавал тему с похожим вопросом: [Проблема с обучением сети в Keras: нет обобщающей способности сети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861009/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-keras-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8), и там получил резонное замечание и совет. Решив попробовать поработать с данными, в которых информация не утрачена (нежели в прошлом топике), я собрал подобную ИНС, предварительно нормализовав данные (использование StandardScaler оказалось лучше MinMax).

Дано:
База из 71 осциллограммы с 3002 отсчетами. Диапазон данных: от 0 до 10Е6. Данные векторы разбиты на обучающую выборку и тестовую (36 и 35).

Задача:
входным векторам присваивать значения на выходе в виде определенного числа (от 30 до 100).

Ограничения:
нет возможности получить огромный датасет (из тысяч векторов) и возможный максимум - сотня-полторы векторов.

Текущая конфигурация сети довольно неплохо обучается (в сравнении с предыдущей), однако проблема с обобщением результатов все также существует. Хоть результат и лучше он все еще не устраивает меня. Меняя конфигурации многослойного персептрона (число нейронов в слое, число слоев) мне не удавалось сильно изменять выходной результат (разве что, кроме времени обучения, что логично). Возможно я не подобрался к самой оптимальной структуре ИНС, но пока есть только это. Кстати да, функцию обучения выбирал методом научного тыка. Перепробовал разные методы и данный показал себя лучше всего.

Итак, отсюда у меня вопросы:
Какие возможные пути изменения ИНС для улучшения результата? К сожалению я все еще новичок в этой области и знаком только с персептронами. Быть может вы сможете посоветовать какие-то другие типы сетей? Если после нормализации у меня диапазон значений вектора от -2 до 6, то как это влияет? На сколько мне известно, то на вход сети следует подавать данные в диапазоне [0 1] или [-1 1].

Код сети:

```
#загружаем файл с образами
TRAIN_FILE="TRAIN30_100km.csv"
TEST_FILE="TEST30_100km.csv"

# размер вектора
img_rows, img_cols = 1, 3002

# Загружаем данные для обучения
train_dataset = np.loadtxt(TRAIN_FILE, skiprows=0, dtype='int', 
delimiter=",")
test_dataset = np.loadtxt(TEST_FILE, skiprows=0, dtype='int', delimiter=",")

# Выделяем данные для обучения
X_train = train_dataset[:, 1:]
X_test = test_dataset[:, 1:]

# нормализуем данные
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train=scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
x_test=scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

# Выделяем правильные ответы
y_train = train_dataset[:,0]
y_test = test_dataset[:,0] 

# рисуем график нормализованного вектора и оригинального
y10 = x_train[6, :]
y11=X_train[6, :]
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.plot(y10)
plt.show()
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.plot(y11)
plt.show()

# Выделяем правильные ответы
y_train = train_dataset[:,0]
y_test = test_dataset[:,0]

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=3002, 
activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu', 
kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile( optimizer='Adagrad', loss="mse", metrics=['mae'])

print(model.summary())
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=1, 
verbose=2,validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

> Epoch 30/30
>    - 0s - loss: 0.9548 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1053 - val_loss: 102.0822 - val_mean_absolute_error: 7.7214

```
mse, mae = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
predictions=model.predict(x_test)
print(predictions)
# ответы (правильные 31 33 35 37)
[20.31354 ]
[18.931906]
[21.085878]
[20.537167]
```

Ссылка на [датасет](https://yadi.sk/d/L_Q7ow-I3Zgwc8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного подумав, решил упростить НС по-максимуму и получил лучшие показатели.

Архитектура:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=3002, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile( optimizer='Adagrad', loss="mse", metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=300, batch_size=3, 
                 verbose=2,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                 callbacks=callbacks)
```

вывод:

```
Epoch 00147: val_mean_squared_error did not improve from 13.76798
Epoch 148/300
 - 0s - loss: 183.8615 - mean_absolute_error: 10.9775 - mean_squared_error: 180.3115 - val_loss: 23.7155 - val_mean_absolute_error: 3.2763 - val_mean
_squared_error: 20.1659

Epoch 00148: val_mean_squared_error did not improve from 13.76798
Epoch 00148: early stopping
```

оценка:

```
In [206]: model = load_model(model_fn)

In [207]: model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)
18/18 [==============================] - 2s 135ms/step
Out[207]: [17.30735206604004, 3.1715924739837646, 13.767986297607422]
```

сравнение тестового набора с предсказанными значениями:

```
In [208]: from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error

In [209]: df = pd.DataFrame({'y_test':y_test.ravel(), 'y_pred':model.predict(x_test).ravel()})

In [210]: mean_squared_error(df['y_test'], df['y_pred'])
Out[210]: 13.76798614917061

In [211]: mean_absolute_error(df['y_test'], df['y_pred'])
Out[211]: 3.171592500474718

In [212]: df['abs_err'] = np.abs(df['y_test'] - df['y_pred'])

In [213]: df
Out[213]:
    y_test     y_pred   abs_err
0     39.0  41.414223  2.414223
1     41.0  38.207268  2.792732
2     43.0  49.000561  6.000561
3     73.0  73.476303  0.476303
4     33.0  32.048149  0.951851
5     78.0  76.682877  1.317123
6     53.0  57.643074  4.643074
7     54.0  58.276382  4.276382
8     67.0  63.092651  3.907349
9     49.0  53.009842  4.009842
10    89.0  87.252930  1.747070
11    65.0  62.399197  2.600803
12    63.0  68.281502  5.281502
13    58.0  55.078934  2.921066
14    48.0  43.649544  4.350456
15    80.0  72.487808  7.512192
16    60.0  60.331455  0.331455
17    47.0  45.445320  1.554680

In [217]: df[['y_test','y_pred']].plot()
Out[217]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xbde07710>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробовав у себя подобный подход и поменяв число нейронов на 300, получил точность на тестовой и валидационной выборках mean_absolute_error: 3.4

Извините за дополнительный вопрос. Возможно он покажется вам глупым, но я не совсем понял механизм построения графика и подпись по оси абсцисс. Я правильно понимаю, что вы выделили массив "ответов" и массив "предсказаний" сети? Но я не совсем смог разобрать код.

Comment: Как вам удалось перемешать выборку для теста так, чтобы варианты шли вразнобой?

Comment: @Aleksandr, обратите внимание на использование `train_test_split()` в `get_data()` - я сделал это чтобы увеличить обучающий набор и чтобы перетасовать данные... PS использовать 50% данных для тестирования - непозволительная роскошь когда у вас всего 71 строки данных...

Comment: Я встречал информацию, что всю базу стоит делить на 0.7 - тренировочные, 0.15 и 0.15 - тестовые и валидационные данные. Просто было интересно посмотреть какой можно получить результат имея столько.
А можно ли в рамках этой же задачи обучить сеть дополнительно на "шумных" образах, то есть ответ тот же, но вот амплитуда и фронт импульсов (оригинальных) слегка изменен? Если можно, то достаточно в рамках этого же кода просто провести model.fit ,где x_train будут эти самые "шумные" образы? Таким образом я смогу увеличить датасет

Comment: @Aleksandr, не вижу проблем в том, чтобы попробовать данный подход...

Comment: Я правильно представляю данный подход:
model.fit (обучаем на одной серии векторов)
model.fit(прогоняем следущую серию)
...
прогоняем все имеющиеся серии?
Мы просто ведь изменяем весовые коэффициенты, решая более общую задачу?

Comment: Тогда, наверное, лучше будет объединить два обучающих набора в один - больший набор и обучить НС на нем...

Answer (score 2):

Немного поигрался с вашими данными - лучшее что у меня получилось:

```
mae: 3.8784
mse: 22.78249
```

вот весь код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
from keras.regularizers import l2, l1
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import save_model, load_model

def get_data(path, test_size=0.25):
    data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in Path(path).glob('*.csv')],
                     ignore_index=True).values
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    x, y = scaler.fit_transform(data[:, 1:]), data[:, [0]]
    return train_test_split(x, y, test_size=test_size)

path = r'/path/to/directory_with_data'
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = \
    get_data(path, test_size=0.25)

model_fn = str(Path(path) / 'model.h5')
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mean_squared_error', min_delta=0.0001,
                           patience=60, verbose=1, mode='auto')
chkpt = ModelCheckpoint(model_fn, 
                        monitor='val_mean_squared_error', 
                        verbose=1, 
                        save_best_only=True, 
                        mode='auto')
callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(45, input_dim=3002, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.04))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dropout(0.01))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile( optimizer='adam', loss="mse", metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=300, batch_size=3, 
                 verbose=2,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                 callbacks=callbacks)
```

[Сохраненная модель ...](https://filebin.net/7ip7nhidmzndcp34/model.h5?t=y57pcslt)

Comment: Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь запустить у себя get_data, но не получается. Код скопировал в jupiter notebook path прописал свой, даже выделил отдельную папку для этого файла с датасетом.
При запуске я получию сл ошибку "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", которая ссылается на data = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header=None) for f in Path(path).glob('*.csv')],
Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Aleksandr, пардон, забыл что у меня “from pathlib import Path” импортируется автоматически при запуске Jupyter